# How to save in NSUserDefaults a array of object?

Tags: swift, nsuserdefaults, xcode6

I need save in `NSUserDefaults` an array or other structure of data to save objects with this format:

```
name = "myName", lastName = "myLastName"
```

I was trying to do this with an array of arrays but this can't save in `NSUserDefaults`.

Now I am trying with a custom class with structure to create objects and append to the array, but also get an error when trying to save this to `NSUserDefaults`. I need save with this structure, but I don't know what is the correct form. How would I do this?

```
var taskMgr: TaskManager = TaskManager()

struct task {
    var name = "Un-Named"
    var lastName = "Un-lastNamed"
}

class TaskManager: NSObject {

    var tasks : [task] = []

    func addTask(name : String, lastName: String){
        tasks.append(task(name: name, lastName: desc))
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you read the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSUserDefaults/setObject:forKey:)?

Answer (score 5):

`NSUserDefaults` expects the stored objects to all be property list objects, i.e. instances of `NSArray`, `NSDictionary`, `NSString`, `NSNumber`, `NSData`, or `NSDate`. Your struct isn't one of those. You'll need to convert your objects to property list types before you store them. One way to do that is to use `NSKeyedArchiver` and the `NSCoding` protocol to write your structs into an instance of `NSData`.

Comment: It is possible to write Swift String and NSArray of String. Ex that work: defaults.setObject("obj2", forKey:"key") and defaults.setObject(["val3", "val4"] as NSArray, forKey: key) –  Zaph 57 secs ago    edit